# Vaadin "Analyze Layout (GWT)" resolve view

Tags: java, gwt, layout, vaadin

There is a Vaadin table containing a row of the panel and another table (Debug window reports no errors in the interface):

Tables props:

```
table.setPageLength(0);
```

After adding rows to a sub table:

[image]

But as soon as I press the button "Analyze Layout" in Debug window, interface looks like this (problem resolved):

[image]

Can I call the "Analyze Layouts" on the server when I need it?

Comment: It really annoys me that I can't remember how I solved exactly the same problem about a year ago. Which version of Vaadin are you using? Would you like to provide some more code?